# Creating a table with matplotlib, columns with floats and other column with strings?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

I want to create a Matplotlib figure with only a table in it, this table should be something like this created in Matlab:

[image: Table created in Matlab]

I need to display columns with floats, and a column with strings for "Unidades".

I tried to make that in Python with Matplotlib, Numpy, Pandas and Spyder.
Note: the table and data are not the same as the picture made with Matlab, but I need the same structure of that table.I'm still missing the title for the table.

After trying several times, having problems to merge floats and string into a Numpy array for plotting, I came up with this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# hide axes
fig.patch.set_visible(False)
ax.axis('off')
ax.axis('tight')

mlamb=  10.03724236064883
d=  0.48815610164066126 #[m]
e=  4.8815610164066126 #[mm]
v=  1.0495771928993183 #[m/s]
f=  0.04161227375782485
p1=  5.976000000000005 #[MPa]
X=  4.8459009928884695
N=  1529.742063492065 #[kW]
k3=  4.851121433427204 #[$/kW]
k03=  7420964.511821515 #[$]

parametros=np.around(np.array([mlamb,d,e,v,f,p1,X,N,k3,k03]),3)
string_magnitudes=str(parametros)
propiedades=np.array(["-lambda","Diametro","Espesor","Velocidad",
                      "Factor de friccion","Presion p1","Plantas de bombeo (X)"
                      ,"Potencia","k3","k03"])
unidades=np.array(["-","m","mm","m/s","-","MPa","unidades","kW","$/kW","$"])

datos=np.zeros((10,2),str)
for r in range(0,len(parametros)):
    datos[r,0]=parametros[r]
    datos[r,1]=parametros[r]

df = pd.DataFrame(datos, columns=['Magnitud','Unidad'])

ax.table(cellText=df.values, rowLabels=propiedades, colLabels=df.columns, cellLoc='center', loc='center')

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

But the problem here is that it only display the first character of each element

[image: Bad table with Matplotlib]

Another issue that I had was that the table was cut off in the column with the rows names, is there a method to format the cells so they fit the data with no/little spare space?

Thanks!

Edit1:
Thanks to @William Miller I could print the table. But when I use this method to make the same original table (the Matlab one) I have the other issue described in the original question that the graph get cut in the column with the rowLabels, here is the code for the complete original table:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# hide axes
fig.patch.set_visible(False)
ax.axis('off')
ax.axis('tight')


parametros=np.array(["Diámetro comercial (dcom)","Espesor comercial (ecom)",
                     "Plantas de bombeo (X)","Factor de fricción (f)",
                     "Presión inicial (p1)",
                     "Variación de presión total (Delta Ptot)",
                     "Variación de presión entre plantas de bombeo (DeltaPx)",
                     "Presión final (p2)"])

unidades=np.array(['m','mm','-','-','MPa','MPa','MPa','MPa'])

datos_caso1=np.array([0.457, 5.6, 4, 0.04080925, 5.976, 36.67886619,
                      9.16971655, -3.19371655])
datos_caso2=np.array([0.457, 5.6, 5, 0.04080925, 5.976, 36.67886619,
                      7.33577324, -1.35977324])
datos_caso3=np.array([0.508, 5.6, 4, 0.04216189, 5.976, 23.7697998 ,
                      5.94244995, 0.03355005])
datos_caso4=np.array([0.508, 5.6, 5, 0.04216189, 5.976, 23.7697998 ,
                      4.75395996,  1.22204004])



df = pd.DataFrame({'Caso 1' : datos_caso1.tolist(),
                   'Caso 2' : datos_caso2.tolist(),
                   'Caso 3' : datos_caso3.tolist(),
                   'Caso 4' : datos_caso4.tolist(),
                   'Unidad' : unidades.tolist()})

ax.table(cellText=df.values, rowLabels=parametros, colLabels=df.columns, cellLoc='center', loc='center')

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Edit2: I forgot to add the cut table image, here it is:[image: Cut final table]

Edit3: Find a no so fancy solution. In the image box there is a button that allows to modify the positioning of the table (I didn't know that when I posted the question). I modify the values in this dialog box:
[image: Positioning configuration box]
Then I looked into Matplotlib [Matplotlib adjust documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html) and finally added this line in the code `plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.97, bottom=0.08, left=0.205, right=0.98, hspace=0.20,wspace=0.20)` I had to comment this line `fig.tight_layout()` to make the changes work.

This is the final result:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# hide axes
fig.patch.set_visible(False)
ax.axis('off')
ax.axis('tight')


parametros=np.array(["Diametro comercial (dcom)","Espesor comercial (ecom)",
                     "Plantas de bombeo (X)","Factor de friccion (f)",
                     "Presion inicial (p1)",
                     "Variacion de presion total (Delta Ptot)",
                     "Variacion de presion entre plantas de bombeo (DeltaPx)",
                     "Presion final (p2)"])

unidades=np.array(['m','mm','-','-','MPa','MPa','MPa','MPa'])

datos_caso1=np.array([0.457, 5.6, 4, 0.04080925, 5.976, 36.67886619,
                      9.16971655, -3.19371655])
datos_caso2=np.array([0.457, 5.6, 5, 0.04080925, 5.976, 36.67886619,
                      7.33577324, -1.35977324])
datos_caso3=np.array([0.508, 5.6, 4, 0.04216189, 5.976, 23.7697998 ,
                      5.94244995, 0.03355005])
datos_caso4=np.array([0.508, 5.6, 5, 0.04216189, 5.976, 23.7697998 ,
                      4.75395996,  1.22204004])



df = pd.DataFrame({'Caso 1' : datos_caso1.tolist(),
                   'Caso 2' : datos_caso2.tolist(),
                   'Caso 3' : datos_caso3.tolist(),
                   'Caso 4' : datos_caso4.tolist(),
                   'Unidad' : unidades.tolist()})

ax.table(cellText=df.values, rowLabels=parametros, colLabels=df.columns, cellLoc='center', loc='center')

plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.97, bottom=0.08, left=0.205, right=0.98, hspace=0.20,
                    wspace=0.20)
#fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does the same cutting happen if you use `plt.savefig()` instead of `plt.show()`?

Comment: Yes, it does the same, I didn't give the `plt.savefig()` any arguments I don't know how to specify the path to a file, or if it's necessary to do so.

Comment: Example usage for windows would be `plt.savefig("C:/Users/username/Documents/plotname.png")`. When I run your exact code (without accents on any characters) I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce79W.png) so it must be to do with how the image is being displayed or saved.

Comment: That's strange. I'm still getting the same cutted image specifying the path with `plt.savefig("C:/Users/username/Documents/plotname.png")` , or showing the image with `plt.show()` both with or without the accents. I'm using 1920x1080p notebook screen, do you have the same screen resolution?

Comment: What does it look like if you comment out `fig.patch.set_visible`?

Comment: It did the same, but I find a no so fancy solution. In the image box there is a button that allows to modify the positioning of the table (I didn't know that when I posted the question). I modify the values in this dialog box https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzh5E.jpg , then I looked into Matplotlib https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html and finally added this line in the code `plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.97, bottom=0.08, left=0.205, right=0.98, hspace=0.20,wspace=0.20)` I had to comment this line `fig.tight_layout()` to make the changes work. Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell you how to prevent `pandas` from truncating the strings but you can get around it by passing the constructor, `pd.DataFrame()`, the data as two lists, as in

```
pd.DataFrame({'Magnitud' : parametros.tolist(), 'Unidad' : unidades.tolist()})
```

This will truncate the strings in the second column of the dataframe.

#### Complete example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=200)

# hide axes
fig.patch.set_visible(False)
ax.axis('off')
ax.axis('tight')

mlamb=  10.03724236064883
d=  0.48815610164066126 #[m]
e=  4.8815610164066126 #[mm]
v=  1.0495771928993183 #[m/s]
f=  0.04161227375782485
p1=  5.976000000000005 #[MPa]
X=  4.8459009928884695
N=  1529.742063492065 #[kW]
k3=  4.851121433427204 #[$/kW]
k03=  7420964.511821515 #[$]

parametros=np.around(np.array([mlamb,d,e,v,f,p1,X,N,k3,k03]),3)
string_magnitudes=str(parametros)
propiedades=np.array(["-lambda","Diametro","Espesor","Velocidad",
                      "Factor de friccion","Presion p1","Plantas de bombeo (X)"
                      ,"Potencia","k3","k03"])
unidades=np.array(["-","m","mm","m/s","-","MPa","unidades","kW","$/kW","$"])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Magnitud' : parametros.tolist(), 'Unidad' : unidades.tolist()})

ax.table(cellText=df.values, rowLabels=propiedades, colLabels=df.columns, 
         cellLoc='center', loc='center')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Table with floats and strings]

Comment: Thank you, this solve 1 problem, but now when I use this method to make the same original table (the Matlab one) I have the other issue described in the original question that the graph get cutted in the column with the rowLabels. I'm posting the code with the data for the complete table next.

Comment: @Azimuth Can you post a picture of the newer problem output?